# fetch() works on some client machines but not all

Tags: typescript, azure-functions, fetch-api

I have a modern style Outlook add-in written in Typescript that fetches XML data from an Azure Web function whenever sending an email.  For most customers, the add-in works great, but for one customer *some* of the client machines in their organization do not get any return results from calling fetch(). These clients cannot send email with the add-in installed.

Using Application Insights, I can see the client call fetch(), see the server side web function receive it and return the appropriate XML data.  BUT, the client never returns from the fetch() call (as I said, only on some machines).

Here's the relevant client side code:

```
    let myXMLData: string = "";
    try {
        debug.Log("Rules.FetchConfigurationFile", "Using fetch");

        const response = await fetch(configurationURL, {
            method: "POST",
            mode: "cors",
            //headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json"},
            body: encodeURIComponent(emailAddress)
        });
        if (!response.ok) {
            myXMLData = "Not found";
            debug.Log("Rules.fetchConfigurationFile", "Rules not found. Response: " + response.status);
            throw response.statusText;
        } else {
            myXMLData = await response.text();
            debug.Log("Rules.fetchConfigurationFile", "Loaded Rules: " + myXMLData);
        }
    } catch (ex) {
      debug.LogException("Error occurred in Rules.FetchConfigurationFile", ex);
    }
    //
    // And decode any encoded XMLData.
    //
    let decodedXMLData: string = decodeURIComponent(myXMLData);
    return decodedXMLData;
  }
```

debug.Log() is a call to Application Insights.  When I look at a successful call from one of the clients, this is what I see:

timestamp [UTC]         message
7/6/2022, 10:53:23.946 PM   Rules.FetchConfigurationFile: Using fetch
7/6/2022, 10:53:25.076 PM   Rules.fetchConfigurationFile: Loaded Rules:  [snip...]

When it fails, this is all I see:
7/6/2022, 10:48:59.829 PM   Rules.FetchConfigurationFile: Using fetch

There are no exceptions or error messages. I can see the web function returning the needed XML but at this point the client is stuck trying to send the email.

I compared various parameters between a successful and unsuccessful call like client OS (both Windows 10), Browser Type (both Edg 103.0), sdkVersion (both javacript 2.5.9) - everything is identical.

How can I debug this?

TIA!

Comment: probably networking issue on their side. Do they have a firewall or something that could block the request ?

Comment: No firewall.  Customer indicates that it seems to be timing related, in that it doesn't work from 7am to around 8 or 815am then it magically starts working.  Why doesn't fetch return a failed response?

Comment: It's an issue on their side. Nothing you can do really